# Con qué tabla relacionar la tabla plan

Tags: mysql-workbench

Tengo una base de datos que registra ventas y compras y también lleva un plan de ventas, con que tabla debería de relacionar la tabla plan, con el producto o con la tabla donde llevo las ventas

Comment: La pregunta resulta curiosa por la complejidad del sistema y lo novato de la pregunta. Podrías cargar la estructura de tus tablas y el DBMS que usas? Sin eso, va a estar difícil. Edita la pregunta, no añadas una respuesta. De paso, leete [esto] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.